# Error al iniciar Payara En netbeans 8.2

Tags: netbeans

Tengo un problema con el servidor payara version 5.
LO descargue y lo agregue directamente desde agregar servidor pero lo inicio y me sale un erro que es este.
Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal [9|]--add-
opens=java.rmi.sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED

Intente desde los plugins de netbeans pero no me deja me sale que faltan varios plugins los cuales no encuentro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tengo el mismo inconveniente. He solucionado mediante el uso la ventana cmd de windows inicializando de forma manual utilizando los siguientes comandos

Luego con el localhost:8080 para abrir la consola de payara.

[image: imagen]